# iPad won't send messages on IMessage

Tags: ipad

My iPad will not send messages or receive I'm connected to wifi I can send them but the send bar at the top will go almost all the way then stop and say about thirty seconds later not delivered

Comment: Can you visit sites in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Internet traffic moves through a firewall based on service-identification numbers that are referred to as ports. Certain ports must be open for FaceTime and iMessage to work.
Here [is a link where you can find the ports to open](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4245).

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first time you've used iMessage on this iPad, use or have you had previous success with sending and receiving on this iPad?

If this is your first use, make sure you've set up iMessage with your AppleID, and linked the proper additional connections (eg: other email addresses or mobile phone numbers).

If you have successfully used iMessage on this iPad before...

- What has changed with your complete environment since the last time you used it?
- Router port settings?
- Installed other programs on the iPad (unlikely)?
- Let anyone else play with your iPad?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and I was typing in the subject field instead of the message field. Pilot error...